# Why My OSX app can not get drag-and-drop from Photos.app

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have subclass a NSView with `NSDraggingDestination` to handle drag-and-drop function. Now, I can get `draggingEntered`, `draggingUpdated`, `performDragOperation` callback when I drag a file from Finder to my view.

But when I drag a picture from Photos.app to my view. there is no any function be called. no `draggingEntered`, `draggingUpdated`, `performDragOperation`.

I use below function to register
`[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];`

PS. OSX version 10.11.6, XCode 7.3

Does anyone know how to get callback when drag picture from Photos.app? Thank you for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can my OS X app accept drag-and-drop of picture files from Photos.app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110525/how-can-my-os-x-app-accept-drag-and-drop-of-picture-files-from-photos-app)

Comment: I have checked this link, but in answer, it can get these callback, but I can not get any. :(

Comment: Did you register for promised files?