# Receive promised e-mail in macOS 10.12+

Tags: cocoa, swift3, swift4, nspasteboard

Previously, I was using the following to discover e-mail meta-data from a drag & dropped e-mail(/-thread) from Mail.app.

```
        if let filenames = draggingInfo.namesOfPromisedFilesDropped(atDestination: URL(fileURLWithPath: destinationDir!)) {
            /// TODO: in future implementation Mail might return multiple filenames here.
            ///         So we will keep this structure to iterate the filenames
            //var aPaths: [String] = []
            //for _ in filenames {
                if let aPath = pb.string(forType: "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url") {
                    return aPath
                }
            //}
            //return aPaths
        }
```

Kind of janky, but it worked, since `"com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url"` was only supplied in those situations.

Since 10.12 however, the API seems to have changed, and looking at the [WWDC2016 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/203/) it appears that Apple wants us to use NSFilePromiseReceiver now.
I've tried a couple of approaches but I can't get a promised file URL to pop out.

Setup:

```
class DropzoneView: NSView {

var supportedDragTypes = [

    kUTTypeURL as String, // For any URL'able types
    "public.url-name", // E-mail title
    "public.utf8-plain-text", // Plaintext item / E-mail thread title / calendar event date placeholder
    "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-content-type", // Calendar event / Web URL / E-mail thread type detection
    "com.apple.mail.PasteboardTypeMessageTransfer", // E-mail thread detection
    "NSPromiseContentsPboardType", // E-mail thread meta-data
    "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url", // E-mail thread meta-data
    "com.apple.NSFilePromiseItemMetaData" // E-mail thread meta-data
]

override func viewDidMoveToSuperview() {
    var dragTypes = self.supportedDragTypes.map { (type) -> NSPasteboard.PasteboardType in
        return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(type)
    } // Experiment:
    dragTypes.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileContentsType(forPathExtension: "eml"))
    dragTypes.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileContentsType(forPathExtension: "emlx"))

    self.registerForDraggedTypes(dragTypes)
}

}
```

Handling:

```
extension DropzoneView {

override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    return .copy
}

override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    return .copy
}

override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {

    let pasteboard: NSPasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
            guard let filePromises = pasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSFilePromiseReceiver.self], options: nil) as? [NSFilePromiseReceiver] else {
        return false
    }

    var files = [Any]()
    var errors = [Error]()

    let filePromiseGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    let newTempDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: (NSTemporaryDirectory() + (UUID().uuidString) + "/"), isDirectory: true)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: newTempDirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch {
        return false
    }

    // Async attempt, either times out after a minute or so (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "(null)") or gives 'operation cancelled' error
    filePromises.forEach({ filePromiseReceiver in
        filePromiseGroup.enter()
        filePromiseReceiver.receivePromisedFiles(atDestination: newTempDirectoryURL,
                                                 options: [:],
                                                 operationQueue: operationQueue,
                                                 reader: { (url, error) in
                                                    Swift.print(url)
                                                    if let error = error {
                                                        errors.append(error)
                                                    }
                                                    else if url.isFileURL {
                                                        files.append(url)
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        Swift.print("No loadable URLs found")
                                                    }

                                                    filePromiseGroup.leave()
        })
    })

    filePromiseGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main,
                            execute: {
                                // All done, check your files and errors array
                                Swift.print("URLs: \(files)")
                                Swift.print("errors: \(errors)")
    })

    Swift.print("URLs: \(files)")

    return true
}
```

Other attempts:

```
    // returns nothing
    if let filenames = pasteboard.propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url")) as? NSArray {
        Swift.print(filenames)
    }

    // doesn't result in usable URLs either
    if let urls = pasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSPasteboardItem.self /*NSURL.self, ???*/], options: [:]) as? [...
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get the file to "pop out" but I cannot get the details for them. It transfers immediately and then hangs for 60 seconds before returning an error message.

Maybe it's a clue but the checkExtension method never returns unless commented out and set to true.

Hopefully this helps kick the can down the road a bit:

```
class DropView: NSView
{
    var filePath: String?

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor

        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType
            .fileNameType(forPathExtension: ".eml"), NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.filePromise])
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        // Drawing code here.
    }

    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if checkExtension(sender) == true
        {
            self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
            return .copy
        }
        else
        {
            return NSDragOperation()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func checkExtension(_ drag: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool
    {
        return true
//        guard let board = drag.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "com.apple.mail.PasteboardTypeMessageTransfer")) as? NSArray,
//            let path = board[0] as? String
//            else
//            {
//                return false
//            }
//
//        let suffix = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).pathExtension
//        for ext in self.expectedExt
//        {
//            if ext.lowercased() == suffix
//            {
//                return true
//            }
//        }
//        return false
    }

    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?)
    {
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor
    }

    override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo)
    {
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool
    {

        let pasteboard: NSPasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()

        guard let filePromises = pasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSFilePromiseReceiver.self], options: nil) as? [NSFilePromiseReceiver] else {
            return false
        }

        print ("Files dropped")
        var files = [URL]()

        let filePromiseGroup = DispatchGroup()
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        let destURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/andrew/Temporary", isDirectory: true)
        print ("Destination URL: \(destURL)")

        filePromises.forEach ({ filePromiseReceiver in
            print (filePromiseReceiver)
            filePromiseGroup.enter()

            filePromiseReceiver.receivePromisedFiles(atDestination: destURL,
                                                     options: [:],
                                                     operationQueue: operationQueue,
                                                     reader:
                                                     { (url, error) in
                                                        print ("Received URL: \(url)")
                                                        if let error = error
                                                        {
                                                            print ("Error: \(error)")
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            files.append(url)
                                                        }
                                                        print (filePromiseReceiver.fileNames, filePromiseReceiver.fileTypes)

                                                        filePromiseGroup.leave()
                                                     })
        })

        filePromiseGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main,
                                execute:
                                {
                                    print ("Files: \(files)")
                                    print ("Done")
                                })
        return true
    }

}
```

The output of this is a bit weird. The url variable aways repeats the name of the directory that I passed in eg

```
Files dropped
Destination URL: file:///Users/andrew/Temporary/
<NSFilePromiseReceiver: 0x6000000a1aa0>

** one minute gap **

Received URL: file:///Users/andrew/Temporary/Temporary/
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "(null)"
["Temporary"] ["com.apple.mail.email"]
Files: []
Done
```

Comment: Thanks @iphaaw, the plot thickens! I actually submitted a support request to Apple and got it refunded with a message saying they're "aware of the issue but currently have no fix or workaround or indication on when it will be fixed"... I retracted my app from the app store and moved on to non-osx projects.

Comment: @AlexMan Did you file a Radar for this? Do you have a link for me? I just tested with the developer beta of Mojave and the behavior is still unchanged.

Comment: @GüntherEberl Did now. Mine was marked as duplicate. Duplicated bug currently still `Open`. https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6079749554176000

Comment: @AlexMan I see, so our issue is in Apple's mystery land now. I guess the fact that it' still open can be seen as positive though. Thanks.

Comment: Apple still didn’t fix this in Monterey. But the weird thing is, you can actually drag-and-drop a mail from Apple Mail to Finder and an EML file will be generated at the location. I guess Finder just doesn’t use the same API.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error when trying to receive promised files to an invalid destination url.

In my case I was using [Ole Begemann's Temporary File Helper](https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/temp-file-helper/) and accidentally letting it go out of scope, which deleted the directory before anything could be copied.

`receivePromisedFiles` gave me the -1001 timeout error after a long wait, but it did still pass a URL that *would* have been correct given my inputs. Obviously no file was at that location.

When I changed to a valid url all worked as expected. It might be worth checking Sandbox issues etc.

Apple now have some useful example projects in the File Promises section here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard